# How to optimise SQL query without using NOT IN

Tags: sql

I have this `Student` table:

```
Id   companyId    status
----------------------------------------
101  1001         In-Progress
102  1001         In-Progress
103  1001         Final
104  1002         In-Progress   
105  1003         Pending With Company 
106  1003         In-Progress
107  1004         In-Progress
108  1004         In-Progress 
109  1005         In-Progress
110  1005         Completed
111  1006         In-Progress
112  1006         Canceled
113  1007         In-Progress
114  1007         Pending with Student
```

I want output with these conditions:

1. Status is "In-Progress"
2. If have repeated companyId then other allowed staus is Completed, Canceled (Basically only allowed combination of the staus is In-Progress, Completed and Canceled)

With above condition o/p will look like this:

```
Id   companyId    status
--------------------------------
104  1002         In-Progress   
107  1004         In-Progress
108  1004         In-Progress 
109  1005         In-Progress
111  1006         In-Progress
```

We can achieve this by using NOT IN

```
SELECT * 
FROM student
WHERE status = 'In-Progress' 
  AND companyId NOT IN (SELECT companyId FROM student 
                        WHERE status IN ('Final', 'Pending With Company ', 'Pending with Student'));
```

But I'm looking for a solution without using `NOT IN`.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve it using left join and choosing not match rows:

```
   SELECT * FROM student a LEFT JOIN 
   ( SELECT companyId FROM student WHERE status in
   ('Final','Pending With Company ','Pending with Student')) b
   on a.companyid=b.companyId 
   where b.companyId is null
   and a.status = 'In-Progress'
```

Comment: Thanks, 
it is working but is it possible to do it other way around having only acceptable state 
like:
Status IN (Completed, Canceled).

Comment: It'll be much more complex. You need to create sub query or CTE that contains only statuses, and inner not in statement, and then you can use IN from the main query

Answer (score 2):

You can use not exists

```
SELECT * 
  FROM student a
 WHERE a.status = 'In-Progress' 
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT null
                     FROM student b
                    WHERE a.companyid=b.companyid
                      AND b.status not in ('In progress','Completed','Cancelled')
                   )
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment but you still have NOT IN, in your inner query.

Comment: @utpalsharma I presume your problem is related to the performance issue as using `NOT IN` for the dataset returning from the subquery, but not related to some fixed, predefined list of values such as `'In progress'`,`'Completed'`,`'Cancelled'`. eg better to use `NOT EXISTS` rather than `NOT IN` against performance issues.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan yes, I am trying to achieve both.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH status as (
   select 1 as s,'In-Progress' d union all
   select 100 as s,'Final' d union all
   select 100 as s,'Pending With Company' d union all
   select 100 as s,'Pending with Student' d union all
   select 1 as s,'Cancelled' d union all
   select 1 as s,'Completed'
)
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT 
      s.Id, 
      s.CompanyID, 
      s.status,
      MAX(status.s) OVER (partition by s.CompanyId) m
   FROM student s
   LEFT jOIN status ON s.status = status.d
) x where x.m=1 and x.status='In-Progress'
```

Remember, above is simply not using `NOT IN`. Discussion about this query not being performant is different.

Comment: This will return all rows with `status='In-Progress'`

Comment: @forpas: sorry got lost in the description of this problem. (edited my answer)

Comment: Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6982e06072503e1b1420b8f703c1729a

Comment: Thank you, but this will not give the expected output.

Comment: Ok, final edit, see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4fcc78a4aa01136903bd58be71a31054